# Playing Simple PHP Dom Parser In Advance

Tags: php, parsing, dom

I want to do something advanced with [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net) but can't understand how to do so..

What I want to do: Suppose we are getting some url from here

```
foreach($result->find('a') as $element)
$element->href
```

and now i want to get its content as plain text but note that I am going to fetch full content from that pages.

Suppose this script has a variable called `$sn = 'linkin park song';` - is there any way to fetch lines from those pages which have the keywords from `$sn`

If you don't understand what I want to do then here is a example.

Suppose `$sn = 'Google 2012 Earning Report';` so PHP SIMPLE DOM PARSER will get some url from `$element->href` , such as:

```
http://www.dailytech.com/Google+Q2+2012+Earnings+Rise+11+Percent+Deals+with+Falling+Ad+PricesMotorola+Issues/article25221.htm
```

It will fetch plain text from this url, which match `$sn`:

```
Google's Q2 2012 earning are looking good despite certain issues ...
Google's latest Earning Report is result of its ability to better target...
```

Comment: it seems like how Google, bing fetch content for search results..

Comment: So you're parsing out a bunch of links, then you want to get the contents of the pages behind those links, *then* get the lines which match a certain keyword from the fetched content? Have you tried *downloading* the individual content? The job of the DOM parser is already done...

Comment: sorry its not giving me sense ...

Comment: You are looking for functions that can match text ($sn) inside another text (your download). You will still need to fetch the whole document first, and then try to match/extract the portions of the text that you want to have. You can use http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php PHPs string functions, or regular expressions.

Comment: can we get idea from here> http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/index.htm#fragment-12